# IndexOutOfBounds Exception within constructor

Tags: java

```js
public constructor (int x)
{
  
  
  try 
    {
      this.x = x;
      if (x < 1 || x> MAX)
  
  }
  
  catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
    
    {
      
      // array allocat
      // calim error
    
    
    }
      
  
  }
```

If I have a constructor that accepts an int parameter that needs to be in [1, MAX), how would I properly utilize the IndexOutOfBOundsException, if the parameter is not within the interval? and if it is then allocate memory for an OBJ[] x array. I thought I could just use if else, but that is not the same behavior

Comment: what is wrong with if else condition ?

Comment: What code did you try? Also, `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is probably not the best choice for that, you might instead want to use [`InvalidParameterException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/InvalidParameterException.html).

Comment: if parameter is not in interval, you should throw IllegalArgumentException in constructor

Comment: okay I did not want to use a if else. so would I format with a try block and set the int paramter to the attribute and then check with if else to see if it is with in interval if not then set up a catch?

Comment: as a side note, throwing an exception in a constructor is often a bad idea

Comment: yeah this was just in specs I am following

Answer (score 0):

Why not, use if else?

Why can't you try something like this..

```
try{
    //Your code
}catch(IndexOutOfBOundsException e){ 
     if(){ // your 1st cond
     }
     else if(){// your 2nd cond
     }
}
```

Comment: okay so I want to the constructor to throw an exception if paramter is not with in the interval [0, MAX), otherwise allocate mem for an array

Comment: wouldnt I check before the catch to see if it is within the range then if it isnt catch?

Comment: you can achieve the  same by simple if, else statement without throwing any exception, or using using an exception. why would you want to make constructor to throw an exception and catch it, where creating an object?

Comment: these are just specs I am following and that is why I am confused on how to go about doing so

Comment: with regards to the exception

Comment: you don't need try catch here, you can handle it by just using simple if else.

Comment: I understand, but I am required to handle it with an exception, and I really dont understand how I would go about doing it with an exception since like you said and if else would work fine

Comment: okay, so on approach would be to throw an custom exception, when not in range, and the catch it from where it's called.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand why you need an exception, but if you want to enter that catch block you must throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException. Then you can do desired action in catch block.

```
try {
        if (x < 1 || x > MAX)
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e)

    {
        System.err.println("Index must be in 1 - MAX interval.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        //do what you want here
    }
```

Comment: why do you need the throw new key word before the catch here?

Comment: If your aim is entering that catch block, you must throw an exception or make an exception to happen somehow (like using an array in try). Otherwise codes in catch block will be unreachable.